# Why is contract balance zero?

Tags: contract-development, ether, remix

after sending Ether to my contract address, why is `balance` returning zero?

```
function contractBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

Testing on Ropsten, and have also tried in the Remix Javascript VM.

This is the deposit function:

```
function deposit(uint referenceNumber) public payable {
    //add to completed deposits array
}
```

The tx when depositing:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5d0cb3e66f565eecc52ab9f4322613dc2d4c43aacf30f3cf52e1dee8e4cd454f

Then when I call `contractBalance` (now called `daoBalance`):
[image: daoBalance call]

Comment: What's the address of the contract on Ropsten? My assumption would be that either: 1) you did _not_ successfully send ether to the contract, or 2) you're not succeeding in calling this function on the right contract.

Comment: 3) the transaction to send Ether to the contract hasn't been mined

Comment: @smarx Contract address: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xeeda876a08063b734293aec020897595f0677ee2 - See how the Eth balance is 0? Why? I think this is the problem.

Comment: Could you share the full source code? It looks like the `deposit` function is sending the ether back, but it's hard to say why without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

There was an error in my code, causing a transfer to happening immediately, rather than later, and back to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending ether to your contract? 
If I send a value with the fallback and call contractBalance it works as expected.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Balance {

  function () external payable {}

  function contractBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }
}
```

Comment: You do realize you're not supposed to downvote someone just because you assume they downvoted you? Use downvoting for bad quality, not revenge.